# Prove that the complement of a point in a metric space is open.

Tags: self-learning

Caveat Lector :
This has been done before, but I  don’t slavishly want to copy.

Let $A=M-\lbrace x\rbrace$ where $M$ is a metric space. Let $A$ be complementary point and $A \subset M$. $\lbrace

Kaplansky also mentions the closed ball without really defining it.

I have to show Ais open.

Here is 1 approach:
Let the given open ball be $B_r(x)=\lbrace D(x,y) < r\rbrace$. If $y\in A$ then $y\in M$ then $B_r(x)$ is contained in $A$ (can we say subset?) so $M$ is open.

2nd approach:
To show A is open Show $A^{c}$ is inside a closed ball.
This is doable to me

Comment: It is very hard to parse your proof.

Comment: Please read and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: It’s been edited and changed. I hope it’s better. I have trouble using it with curly braces and things

Answer (score 1):

If $A = \emptyset$ then we are done. if $A\neq\emptyset$,

Let $a\in A$. Then set $r=\frac{d(a,x)}{2}$. Then $x\notin B_r(a)$. Thus $B_r(a)\subseteq A$. Thus $a$ is an interor point of $A$. Since $a$ is arbitrarily chosen, each point of $A$ is an interor point. Thus $A$ is open.

Comment: I cannot assume interior points , no definition in the text

Comment: @larrymintz How did you define an open set?

Comment: M is  a metric space, x a point. r.  the radius. D(x,y) < r The set y € M is called an open ball  (Using Kaplansky’s def.)

Comment: That's not the definition of open set...

Comment: @larrymintz check your notes again. I'm pretty sure that's not the definition of an open set.

Comment: That’s an open ball. Theorem 27 Any open ball in M is an open set By this is theorem I guess to rely on triangle inequality I assumed if y€. A I could I deduced M is open being a metric space but I guess I have to prove it

Comment: @larrymintzYes. Any open ball is an open set. But not necessarily vice versa. What is the text anyway?

Comment: Set theory & metric spaces Kaplansky So y€M then implies M has an open ball and have to prove both parts are open

Comment: Page 72: Definition. Let $U$ be a subset of a metric space $M$. We say that $U$
is open in $M$ if for every $x\in U$ an entire open ball $S_r(x)$ is contained in $U$.

That is what I have shown.

Comment: I suppose the radius can be anything as long as they are not equal

Comment: No, you cannot take any radius you want. for instance if you take $r=d(a,x)+1$, then $B_r(a) \nsubseteq A$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104169/discussion-between-larry-mintz-and-gune).

Comment: Thanks anyways. Next time I will state hints at best